# My changes not reflect my php code in my site with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, caching

It's been a few days now, that my changes in the code (controller, event, blade or any other php files) are not reflected at runtime.
For my changes to be taken into consideration, I have to close my code editor (VSCode) and open it again and type the command "npm run watch" even for PHP files.

My working environment is under Window 10 with VSCode, Laravel 8, PHP 7.4.

I specify that I have already tried the following commands:
`php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan event:clear`

That I have already deleted the VSCode cache manually and that I delete the cache of Chrome on every run, but nothing changes except close my project and reopen it and run the "npm run watch" command even if no such file is affected.

Does anyone have an idea for me, because I will soon have no more hair :-D?

Comment: how are you synching  the remote file ? with a version controll like git or are you access it remotely with VSC with an ftp/ssh connexion?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Why are you caching everything in a dev environment?  Caching is for prod environments.  Clear those caches... `php artisan cache:clear`   and stop using them.  Updates should be instant.

Comment: I am working locally with the Wamp server and yes I am in a development environment. I am not using cache in development. However, the only answers I found all indicated to do these commands.

It seems to me that this problem appeared with the change of PHP version (7.3 to 7.4) but I don't see the direct relation.